# WebView will not function with loadUrl but works with loadData

Tags: android, emulation

I'm using standard addresses like google and facebook, but loadUrl does nothing, it just sits there at a white screen, but if i pipe html into it using loadData, it works fine. Any ideas or tips? I've got it enabling javascript, and I have this call:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            TextView t;
            t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pageTitle);
            t.setText(view.getTitle());
        }
    });
```

Do i need to override anything else?

Comment: Does your app request the internet permission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```
public class WebViewSampleActivity extends Activity {
         WebView wb;
        private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);      
            wb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);        
            wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
            wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
            wb.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            wb.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            wb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);           
            wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
            wb.loadUrl("http://www.foo.com");       
        }
    }
```

Comment: and yeah, don't forget to add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> in your manifest file. In your main.xml file, keep layout_xx = "fill parent".

Comment: setting internet permissions was the problem, but someone else already answered this. maybe i submitted the question twice somehow? i dunno.

Comment: Yeah. I saw another copy of this same question posted by you after I answered here.

Answer (score 0):

The discussed above are cool and pretty good but I've noticed this thing in newer versions of android studio the method loadUrl() does not work direct through. so we should identify the settings first then set true for JS as like this

wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
 wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);